# Testing an Oracle Coherence IPortableObject Implementation in .NET

Tags: c#, unit-testing, oracle-coherence

In order to get good test coverage, I want to test the `WriteExternal` and `ReadExternal` methods of `IPortableObject` (as described at [Creating an IPortableObject Implementation (.NET)](http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH34UG/Configuration+and+Usage+for+.NET+Clients#ConfigurationandUsagefor.NETClients-CreatinganIPortableObjectImplementation%28.NET%29) ).

Here is code similar to what I have in my test method (which I like, and it works).

```
Person person = new Person { Name = "John Doe" };
Person personCopy = CoherenceTestHelper.CopyUsingPofSerialization<Person>(person);
Assert.AreEqual(person, personCopy);
```

But to get this to work, I had do subclass `PofStreamWriter` to override `BeginProperty` and `PofStreamReader` to override `AdvanceTo`.  To me this smells a little funny, but I couldn't come up with a better solution.  Below is my actual code for my CoherenceTestHelper.

**Question:** Has anybody else unit tested their `IPortableObject` implementation a better way?

```
public static class CoherenceTestHelper
{
    public static T CopyUsingPofSerialization<T>(T ipoIn) where T : IPortableObject, new()
    {
        T ipoOut = new T();

        IPofContext context = new SimplePofContext();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
        IPofWriter writer = new MyPofStreamWriter(new DataWriter(ms), context);
        ipoIn.WriteExternal(writer);

        ms.Seek(0, 0);
        IPofReader reader = new MyPofStreamReader(new DataReader(ms), context);
        ipoOut.ReadExternal(reader);
        }

        return ipoOut;
    }

    private class MyPofStreamWriter : PofStreamWriter
    {
        public MyPofStreamWriter(DataWriter writer, IPofContext context)
        : base(writer, context)
        {
        }

        protected override void BeginProperty(int index)
        {
        }
    }

    private class MyPofStreamReader : PofStreamReader
    {
        public MyPofStreamReader(DataReader reader, IPofContext context)
        : base(reader, context)
        {
        }

        protected override bool AdvanceTo(int index)
        {
        return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This test is too concerned with the actual execution of the `IPofReader` and `IPofWriter`. I suggest you create a mock of the reader/writer using a framework like [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx). Pass your POF method(s) the mocked reader/writer. Then simply assert that the read/write methods were called with the correct parameters.

Comment: Then I would need a specific mock for each IPortableObject implementation, where this helper can be used against any object.  Also, I want to make sure the calls (e.g. ReadString and WriteString) are balanced and in the same order, which I'm not sure how to mock.  I am concered with the actual execution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into how to unit test IPofSerializer's and I expect it's similar to your problem. What I've found is that in order to correctly serialize and deserialize the user type you have to call PofStreamWriter.WriteObject and PofStreamReader.ReadObject. The user type also has to be registered with the PofContext for this to work correctly.

The reason for this is that the PofStreamWriter class contains a nested subclass that it delgates to when serializing user types. This subclass writes additonal data about the type that the PofStreamReader then uses to correctly deserialize the type. Without this addtional data the PofStreamReader can't determine what type it is and what serializer should be used. It looks like it's just not setup to allow for testing of a serializer in complete isolation as there is to much state maintained internally by the PofStreamReader and PofStreamWriter while serializing.

For testing IPofSerializers I'm doing the following

```
var context = new SimplePofContext()
context.RegisterUserType(1001, typeof(SerializableType), new SerializatableTypeSerializer())

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var writer = new PofStreamWriter(new DataWriter(ms), context);
    writer.WriteObject(0, object);

    ms.Seek(0,0);

    var reader = new PofStreamReader(new DataReader(ms), context);
    var ob = reader.ReadObject(0)
}
```

I suspect, but haven't tested, that for IPortableObjects you don't have to register anything with the context inorder for this to work.